# How to use ObjectListView to show all the images in a imagelist?

Tags: vb.net, imagelist, objectlistview

How do I use a ObjectListView to show all the images in a image-list ? In the home-site of ObjectListView they have shown how to do this in C# (I am not that good with c# and delegates). But I can't get it to work in VB.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct translation of their example:

```
Me.mainColumn.ImageGetter = Function(row As Object) Do
    Dim key As String = Me.GetImageKey(row)
    If Not Me.listView.LargeImageList.Images.ContainsKey(key) Then
        Dim smallImage As Image = Me.GetSmallImageFromStorage(key)
        Dim largeImage As Image = Me.GetLargeImageFromStorage(key)
        Me.listView.SmallImageList.Images.Add(key, smallImage)
        Me.listView.LargeImageList.Images.Add(key, largeImage)
    End If
    Return key
End Function
```

That will only work with the most recent version of VB.NET because it uses an inline function.  You can alter it like this for older versions:

Create a function similar to:

```
Public Function GetImageFromList(row As Object) As String
        Dim key As String = Me.GetImageKey(row)
        If Not Me.listView.LargeImageList.Images.ContainsKey(key) Then
            Dim smallImage As Image = Me.GetSmallImageFromStorage(key)
            Dim largeImage As Image = Me.GetLargeImageFromStorage(key)
            Me.listView.SmallImageList.Images.Add(key, smallImage)
            Me.listView.LargeImageList.Images.Add(key, largeImage)
        End If
        Return key
End Function
```

And then set your image getter for the column to it like:

```
Me.mainColumn.ImageGetter = AddressOf GetImageFromList
```

Comment: What is this image getter ? Is it a control in vb.net ? Will it work in VS2010 ?

Comment: ImageGetter is a delegate property on the column.  You need to write the methods to get the images form your imageList by key.  Those were just examples they provided